# how can I get the value from a HiddenField which created in program?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get the value of the HiddenField in asp. However, the question is that HiddenField is created in program which is not from asp control.

```
     protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        hd = new HiddenField();
        hd.ID = "hdID"
        hd.Value = jsonString;

        this.Controls.Add(hd);

       //........

        base.OnInit(e);
        InitializeControl();
    }
```

Then when I trying to read its value..

```
var text = $("#<%=hdID.ClientID%>").val(); // fail, it says that the hd is not exist..
```

Comment: Where are calling the Jquery function..? It should be in `document.ready()`

Comment: @Vikrant So, is it impossible to  read it outside the document.ready() scope (I need to use it cross js file)?

Comment: as it gets created dynamically, script must be registered after its creation

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = $("#hdID").val();
```

please try it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var text = $("#<%=hdID.ClientID%>").val();
}
```